# Hong Kong Octopus Card 9-Digit UID Read

Tags: nfc, uuid

Is anyone doing HK Octopus card development?  For Octopus follows the FeLiCa standard, and it has a public card mfgID that we can read.  However the Octopus card has a 9-digit UID printed on it, and I'm hoping to read that number from the card using NFC card reader.